# How to hide columns that don't have issues from Kanban board in Jira?

Tags: workflow, jira, kanban

I have about ten statuses and ten columns on the Kanban board in Jira. It makes the text in tickets unreadable. Some of the columns don't have issues in them. Can I show only those columns that currently have issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting to automatically hide columns that don't have any issues in them, but if you're a project administrator (for the location of your board) or a board administrator, then you can [configure which columns to display](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-columns-764477997.html).

Other than that, using the zoom in/out feature of your browser might help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Combine related statuses in a single column.
- Use multiple Kanban boards. This might be useful if the development workflow can be split in separate stages, for instance a Develop stage and a Test stage, where the last status/column of the Develop board is the first status/column of the Test board.

Comment: Hmm, intersting idea about splitting the boards. But does not it mean that I have to split the workflow too?

Comment: You don't need another workflow. A board is just a specific view to the workflow or a selection of workflow steps.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario I wouldn´t use boards. JIRA has gadgets and filters that are much more flexible to do your tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I created a simple extension to hide/show all the empty columns with a single click on the JIRA sprint board. Also, it allows hiding any individual columns you like as well.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clean-jira/icmmenbhnhajjniohcknhppfbimnkjpb